# Get GUI back from background application

Tags: ssh, gui, desktop-background, nohup

I started an app (minecraft server) with ssh like this:

```
nohup java -jar minecraftserver.jar &
```

and then logged out. Now that I am next to my computer I can't access the server's terminal.

How can I get it's GUI back? Or can it be accessed from the terminal in some way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can list all background jobs using `jobs` command:

```
$ jobs -l
[1]+ 15024 Running                 nohup firefox &
```

you can bring the process with `fg` command.

#### BUT

It's better to use [**`screen`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) other than `nohup`. It will detach your commands but you can resume your screen session easily and get the background processes easily.

Take a look for this [screen tutorial](http://www.kuro5hin.org/story/2004/3/9/16838/14935) in addition to the link above